# Swift : Set background color and label text color

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor, uibackgroundcolor

I am trying to change the label text color and view background color. But something is going wrong.

```
    func ItisDark(){
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        questionLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        answerLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        infoBtn.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }

func checkDate(sunrise:NSDate, sunset:NSDate){
    // Date comparision to compare current date and end date.
    let dateComparisionResult:NSComparisonResult = NSDate().compare(sunrise)
    let dateComparision:NSComparisonResult = NSDate().compare(sunset)

    if dateComparisionResult == NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame || dateComparisionResult == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending && dateComparision == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
    {
        //result is
        answerLabel.text = "yes".uppercaseString
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        questionLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        answerLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }else{
        answerLabel.text = "no".uppercaseString
       //here is the problem!
        ItisDark()

    }

}
```

I tried this code in empty project. Everything is perfect. But I'm looking at white screen in another project. What are you thinking about that problem?

Comment: did you call that function into the `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: Hard to say what the problem is when you don't give us any information about the "other project" This is a minimal example, but not verifiable to your problem.. so probably not complete.

Comment: yes i did in empty project and it works. But I'm calling that function in another project, screen being full white. When I delete the label properties, background being white and label text color is black(default).

Comment: you mean another file or project?

Comment: I tried on ViewDidLoad in this project and it works. I edited my question. Please check the "checkdate" function. Here is the problem came from.

Comment: is your `if statement works`

Comment: yes it works. This happened suddenly. Normally this itisdark function works. I don't get it :S